# QGIS plug-in equivalent of ArcGIS's Spatial Analyst Tools -> Overlay/ Weighted Overlay

Tags: qgis, spatial-analyst, overlay

Specifically I have 12 .bil raster files that show monthly global mean minimum temperature. I file for each month. I want to combine these to create an ANNUAL global mean minimum temperature. In Arc I think that Spatial Analyst Tools-> Overlay -> Weighted overlay would be the way to go. Is there an equivalent plug-in for QGIS?